# Semaphore won't work

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I'm trying to create a small program that demonstrates the use of semaphores. I create 2 threads, that run two instances of Farmer: one with the string "north" as a parameter and one with "south". Instead of having 1 thread finish followed by the 2nd, they both seem to finish at the same time (as indictated by the output:

Farmer going over the bridge, heading north
Farmer going over the bridge, heading south
Farmer has crossed the bridge and is now heading north
Farmer has crossed the bridge and is now heading south

Can anyone tell me what I´m doing wrong here?

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
public class Farmer implements Runnable
{
    private String heading;
    private final Semaphore bridge = new Semaphore(1);
    public Farmer(String heading)
    {
        this.heading = heading;
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        if (heading == "north")
        {
            try 
            {
                //Check if the bridge is empty
                bridge.acquire();
                System.out.println("Farmer going over the bridge, heading north");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("Farmer has crossed the bridge and is now heading north");
                bridge.release();
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Farmer crossed the bridge and "releases" it

        }
        else if (heading == "south")
        {
            try 
            {
                //Check if the bridge is empty
                bridge.acquire();
                System.out.println("Farmer going over the bridge, heading south");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                //Farmer crossed the bridge and "releases" it
                System.out.println("Farmer has crossed the bridge and is now heading south");
                bridge.release();
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also you are using == for string comparisons which is never a good idea.  You should use `equals(...)`.  And I see "North" and "north"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each Farmer is creating its own semaphore, which means it can acquire and release it independently from any others.

Change this:

```
private final Semaphore bridge = new Semaphore(1);
```

to this:

```
private final static Semaphore bridge = new Semaphore(1);
```

Then the semaphore will be shared between all Farmer instances.